ImportError (cannot import name 'escape' from 'flask')
I am working on python3 learn the hard way book exercise 52. while running on my nosetests I am getting import error.
ERROR: Failure: ImportError (cannot import name 'escape' from 'flask' (/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/flask/__init__.py))

File "/home/dhivya/projects/gothonweb/tests/app_tests.py", line 2, in <module> from app import app
File "/home/dhivya/projects/gothonweb/app.py", line 1, in <module> from flask import Flask, session, redirect, url_for, escape, request
ImportError: None

My flask installed version and location
Name: Flask
Version: 3.0.2
Summary: A simple framework for building complex web applications.
Home-page:
Author:
Author-email:
License:
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages
Requires: blinker, click, itsdangerous, Jinja2, Werkzeug
Required-by:
I have tried uninstall and reinstall the flask. I think my flask installed location and expected location is different (there is no init.py file) but not sure.can someone help me to resolve this error?

The error you're actually getting is cannot import name 'escape' from 'flask'. There's no issue with flask installation location and the name __init__.py has nothing to do with the error and is a naming convention for python to recognize packages that can be imported and not specific to flask
From flask Version changes

Version 2.3.0
Released 2023-04-25
Importing escape and Markup from flask is deprecated. Import them directly from markupsafe instead. #4996


You're using version 3.0.2 > 2.3.0
So use from markupsafe import escape instead of from flask import escape

Thanks for this clear information. I have already tried this one, but this helps me to understand the error and focus on my next error.
